# Multithreading in UDP Sockets using WIN32 API (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: multithreading, sockets, udp

I am working on a simple UDP Client-Server Application. I have used case WM_TIMER: at the Server Side where Server waits for receiving the data from client using recv_from() Function. But the problem is that the program is not executed further until some data is received. 
I want to hadle all this in a separate thread. In short, I want to create a thread in which this wait is done and all other functionalities are performed simultaneously.

Comment: You don't need a thread in this situation. Put the socket into non-blocking mode and then use `select()`, `WSAAsyncSelect()`, or `WSAAsyncEvent()` to detect when data is ready to read before calling `recvfrom()`. Or use overlapped I/O.  Or use I/O completion ports.

Answer (score 0):

Then go create a thread!

[CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is likely the function you want to call to spin up a thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have successfully created a single thread. Now I want to know is there any Window message (WM_MESSAGE) generated when a thread completes its execution? I don't want to continuously monitor the working of thread. instead, I want that when a thread function is completed, it should generate some COMMAND or MESSAGE itself.

Comment: There is no message for that. Just post your own message when your thread code is finished.

Comment: PostMessage(your_hwnd, WM_USER+1, x, y);

Comment: @selbie
Hey,
your post made my task so easy :) Thank you so much. Your help means a lot :)

Comment: Is there any way in which I can pass a character array from a thread to my main window when PostMessage() is called?

Comment: You could use COM marshalling to easily achieve making a method call onto another thread that has a message pump. But that's pretty tricky stuff.  Otherwise, create your own thread safe message queue data structure, and use PostMessage to signal the other thread to deque a message that the other thread appended to it.